# Image maximum value with SSE instruction

Tags: c++, sse

I'm trying to cede a function that return the maximum value of an image with the use of SSE instruction. I have a strange result of the maximum value set to be -356426400 (the value should be 254).

this is my code :

```
void max_sse(unsigned int *src, long h, long w, unsigned int *val)
{

unsigned int tab[16];
for(int i=0; i<h*w;i+=16)
{
__m128i PG=_mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(&src[i]));
__m128i max=_mm_max_epi8(max,PG);
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&tab, max);
}
*val=tab[0];
for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
if (tab[i]>*val)
{
*val=tab[i];
}
}

}
```

Comment: What format is your image ? Is it really 32 bits per pixel (assuming int is 32 bits) or is each int really, say, RGBA ? And if it's RGB then what sort of maximum are you looking for ? Separate max for each component, or what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I don't see any code dealing with alignment

2) There's a mismatch between unsigned integers and **_mm_max_epi8** which comapares 8-bit signed integers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514045(v=vs.90).aspx)

3) I'm assuming you have a h*w matrix with rows multiple of 4 (or dealing with that with some padding for instance)

On Windows you could do something like:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <malloc.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void max_sse(unsigned int *src, long h, long w, unsigned int *val)
{
    _STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(BYTE)*4);
    if( w % 4 != 0)
        return; // ERROR Can't do it, need 4-multiple rows or do some alignment!
    unsigned int *aligned_src = (unsigned int*)_aligned_malloc(h*w*sizeof(unsigned int), 16); // _mm_load_si128 needs 16-bytes aligned memory
    memcpy(aligned_src, src, sizeof(unsigned int)*h*w);
    __declspec(align(16)) __m128i max = {0,0,0,0};

    // Iterates the matrix
    for(int i=0; i<h*w; i+=4)
    {
        __m128i *pg = (__m128i*)(aligned_src+i);
        __m128i PG = _mm_load_si128(pg);

        __m128i newmax = _mm_max_epu32(max, PG);
        _mm_store_si128(&max, newmax);
    }
    unsigned int abs_max = 0;
    unsigned int *max_val = (unsigned int*)&max;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if (abs_max < *(max_val+i))
        {
            abs_max = *(max_val+i);
        }
    }
    _aligned_free(aligned_src);
    cout << "The max is: " << abs_max << endl;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int src[] = {0,1,2,4, 5,6,7,8, 224,225,226,129};
    unsigned int val;
    max_sse(src, 3,4, &val);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming the **memcpy** a necessary evil in your code since there isn't any other information on memory alignment. If you have something to deal with that, do it yourself and it will be a lot better.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<h*w; i += w)` - this iteration would work properly only when image has 16px in width

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'm working in linux, any idea how i should write the code (i don't have any idea about   _STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(BYTE)*4);
    if( w % 4 != 0)
        return; // ERROR Can't do it, need 4-multiple rows or do some alignment!
    unsigned int *aligned_src = (unsigned int*)_aligned_malloc(h*w*sizeof(unsigned int), 16); // _mm_load_si128 needs 16-bytes aligned memory
    memcpy(aligned_src, src, sizeof(unsigned int)*h*w);
    __declspec(align(16)) __m128i max = {0,0,0,0};

Comment: You can remove them, what I wanted to make sure is that an unsigned integer was 4 system-defined bytes and that width is a multiple of 4 integers for the matrix. _aligned_malloc is Windows-specific and on linux you can use: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html . For __declspec there are gcc's attributes: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html .

@Yossarian You're right sorry, fixed the code..

Comment: Note that you don't need to store load and store the max vector on every iteration.

Comment: I'm a newbie with SSE and I tried to mock the user's code. By the way thanks for the tip, +1 by me!